# Office.initialize not initialized on first time load

Tags: office-js

I developed an `addin` for `excel`, in works fine on windows. But on mac `Office.initialize` is initialized first, every time a have to right click on my `add in` and click reload.
**Updated**
Following is my code

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    console.log("In Office.initialize method");  // it is called when I insert my content pane app excel sheet.
    myFunction();  // This method is not called, when I insert my content pane app excel sheet. When I right click on app, and click reload then is called.
};

function myFunction(){
    console.log("In my function");
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Could you clarify?  What do you expect to happen, and what are you seeing happen?  Also, what build #?

Comment: FWIW, the expected behavior is that Office.initialized should get called whenever the add-in loads and on any page thereafter.  Only when it's called can you safely make OM calls.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft I have updated my question